# Downtime required for 20 GB of Neo4j DB data migration to Neptune

Tags: neo4j, amazon-neptune, downtime, opencypher

I want to migrate 20 GB of Neo4j Graph data to AWS Neptune. how much Neo4j DB downtime is needed for entire data migration and how to handle the data lost during downtime.

Answer (score 2):

Two blog posts that you may want to review include both an initial baseline migration [1] and how to capture changes and perform incremental updates [2].

So long as your existing queries and connection methods work on both platforms (without any modification), you could potentially leverage these two methods to have very minimal downtime.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-a-neo4j-graph-database-to-amazon-neptune-with-a-fully-automated-utility/

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/change-data-capture-from-neo4j-to-amazon-neptune-using-amazon-managed-streaming-for-apache-kafka/

Comment: thanks for the links they are helpful. 
can you please let me know what could be the downtime if we migrate local Neo4j data to AWS EC2 Neo4j Enterprise and how to handle the data lost during downtime

Comment: That heavily depends on the migration process chosen and the write throughput of the application(s) using the database.